# How to get a dynamic sessionid in javascript JMeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter

The `reqIdToken` is `sessionID` and is a defined dynamic variable in javascript code.

```
var reqIdToken = idtoken.slice(-36);
```

How to get `reqIdToken`  value in `JMeter 3.3`?

Answer (score 0):

Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and choose language Javascript and then you can execute javascript, In your case for example, get from token variable and save in sessionId variable:

```
var reqIdToken = vars.get("token").slice(-36);
vars.put("sessionId", reqIdToken);
```